# Matrices for the Life-Sciences

Tags: matrices, mathematical-physics

I was curious to know the usefulness of the matrices in the sciences/biology that regulate our life:
for example, *in the nature*, in our ecosystem, with very simple practical examples for the student of an high school.

Comment: Matrices are a concrete manifestation of the subject properly called *linear algebra*.  Try googling "linear algebra biology".  Or google "eigenvector biology". Systems of differential equations are often studied using tools from linear algebra, even if the system itself is not linear.  Look up Lotka-Volterra equations and Hodgkin-Huxley model.  Are you asking this question for yourself or as motivation for something else (e.g., teaching a course about matrices that will be taken by many life sciences students)?

Comment: Markov Chains are a good basic example, especially in ecology. If you have an ecosystem with a sequence of populations, and want to have a good basic understand the equilibrium, and the rate of convergence to it, you can model if via a Markov chain.

Comment: @KCd Thank you very much of your suggestion...I have improved my question because it is relative for the students of high school. Excuse me for my forgetfulness.

Comment: @PaxKivimae Thank you very much also to you...I appreciated also an answer..is it possibile please?

Comment: @KCd When I explain quickly the matrices to calculate a simple determinant of order 3 (it's enough a success if they understand it) I wanted to give some concrete examples.

Comment: Finding a 3 x 3 determinant is not anything done by hand in the real world (inversion would be done by computer), and I think it's misleading to suggest this *specific* calculation with matrices is related to some amazing applications. What matters in applications is the *general tool* of matrices and operations with them (powers, eigenvectors, etc.).  So tell the students about a range of applications of matrices in mathematical models, not applications of 3 x 3 determinants. Since you don't need to use *life science* applications, instead use settings more relevant to their daily lives:

Comment: search engine optimization, Netflix and other automated recommendation systems, facial recognition, and so on. Google "applicatons of linear algebra" and you'll find a bazillion uses.  It is *not* in practice just $3 \times 3$ matrices: search engine opimiization and automated recommendation systems involves matrices with *thousands* of rows and columns.  Almost no real world uses of linear algebra developed in the last 30 years involve matrices up to size $3 \times 3$.  Thanks to computers, fast calculations can and are made with enormous matrices.

Comment: @KCd My difficulty is that students study very little :-( thank you for your enormous kindness.